# Why do I get the Regexp warning "warning: nested repeat operator ? and * was replaced with '*'"

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regular expression for parsing Norwegian street addresses:

```
STREET_ADDRESS_PATTERN = <<-REGEX
    ^
    (?<street_name>[\w\D\. ]+)\s+
    (?<house_number>\d+)
    (?<entrance>[A-Z])?\s*,\s*
    (
        (?<postal_code>\d{4})\s+
        (?<city>[\w\D ]+)
    )?
    $
REGEX
```

It worked earlier, and I can't remember if I changed something, and in which case *what* I changed. In any case, now I'm getting this warning:

> warning: nested repeat operator ? and * was replaced with '*'

And the match is returning `nil`. Can anybody see why I'm getting this warning?

---

*Note:* I'm currently using this (fake) address to test the expression: "Storgata 38H, 0273 Oslo".

Comment: This looks like a heredoc for a string. Is there such things as a regex heredoc? I think not.

Comment: @sawa: There's no reason you can't create your regex pattern in a heredoc. Any way of constructing a string'll work (depending on language).

Comment: @Sysyphus I don't see any benefit here to write a string heredoc and embed it in a regex. That makes things (such as escaping) complicated. It is also introducing extra computation. If the OP just wanted to write in multiple lines, the OP can use the `x` mode of regex literal.

Comment: For the "I can't remember if I changed something" problem : http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look at something you're doing to the poor regular expression engine:

```
(?<street_name>[\w\D\. ]+)\s+
```

The problem is inside the character class: `[\w\D\. ]+`. The following definitions are from Ruby's [Regexp class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html):

- `/\w/` - A word character `([a-zA-Z0-9_])`
- `/\D/` - A non-digit character `([^0-9])`

You're telling the engine to select:

- `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
- `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
- `0123456789`
- `_`
- every character that is *NOT* `0123456789`
- `.` and spaces

In other words, every possible character. You'd do just as well to use:

```
(?<street_name>.+)
```

because that's going to be pretty greedy. This Rubular example shows your pattern is allowing the engine to capture everything thrown at it, including almost the entire string `Storgata 38H, 0273 Oslo`: http://rubular.com/r/nMfcB0cUdu

Also, `\.` inside `[]` is the same as `[.]` because the special use of period as a wildcard is escaped automatically inside the brackets. You don't need to escape it again to try to make it literal because it already is literal.

I'd strongly recommend using Rubular to take a look at each section of your regex, and try matching against several other possible addresses strings, and see if Rubular says the patterns are going to match what you expect. Once you've done that, try putting together the complete pattern. As is, I think your subsections are interacting and masking some problems that will come back to bite you later.

---

> My hope was that [\w\D] would select all word characters except numbers... Any way to do that?

Ah. Let's dive into [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) again:

> POSIX bracket expressions are also similar to character classes. They provide a portable alternative to the above, with the added benefit that they encompass non-ASCII characters. For instance, /\d/ matches only the ASCII decimal digits (0-9); whereas /[[:digit:]]/ matches any character in the Unicode Nd category.

```
/[[:alnum:]]/ - Alphabetic and numeric character
/[[:alpha:]]/ - Alphabetic character
/[[:blank:]]/ - Space or tab
/[[:cntrl:]]/ - Control character
/[[:digit:]]/ - Digit
/[[:graph:]]/ - Non-blank character (excludes spaces, control characters, and similar)
/[[:lower:]]/ - Lowercase alphabetical character
/[[:print:]]/ - Like [:graph:], but includes the space character
/[[:punct:]]/ - Punctuation character
/[[:space:]]/ - Whitespace character ([:blank:], newline, carriage return, etc.)
/[[:upper:]]/ - Uppercase alphabetical
/[[:xdigit:]]/ - Digit allowed in a hexadecimal number (i.e., 0-9a-fA-F)
```

You want to use the `/[[:alpha:]]/` pattern. As displayed it would capture only one character, but it'd be within any of the POSIX set of "letter" characters, which is the range you want:

```
[4] (pry) main: 0> 'æ, ø and å'.scan(/[[:alpha:]]/)
[
    [0] "æ",
    [1] "ø",
    [2] "a",
    [3] "n",
    [4] "d",
    [5] "å"
]
```

Here's a wee tweak:

```
[5] (pry) main: 0> 'æ, ø and å'.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/)
[
    [0] "æ",
    [1] "ø",
    [2] "and",
    [3] "å"
]
```

Comment: My hope was that `[\w\D]` would select all word characters *except* numbers... Any way to do that? `[a-z]` is not sufficient since I need to match all UTF-8 word characters, including æ, ø and å.

Comment: Also, I didn't mean to hurt the engine.

Comment: The engine survives things that would kill a mortal.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant and perfect answer, mr. Tin Man.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about brilliant or perfect, but it certainly was long-winded. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, now I see what I did. I replaced the `'` delimiters of the string with `<<-REGEX` which means that all backslashes in the expression must now be escaped. Changing back to single ticks fixed the issue. After [sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149392/sepp2k)'s recommendation I further edited the Regex string into a literal:

```
STREET_ADDRESS_PATTERN = /
    ^
    (?<street_name>[\w\D\. ]+)\s+
    (?<house_number>\d+)
    (?<entrance>[A-Z])?\s*,\s*
    (
        (?<postal_code>\d{4})\s+
        (?<city>[\w\D ]+)
    )?
    $
/xi
```

Comment: Why don't you just use regex literals?

Comment: @sepp2k: Because it's a big expression. How do you nicely construct a multi-line regex literal?

Comment: Put a `/` on the first line and another one on the last line. Then put an `x` after the closing `/`, so that it ignores the white space.